# Home button goes to TV app

Tags: appletv

While working with my Apple TV, I noticed that pressing the home button (to the right of the menu button) would instead take me to the TV app.

Is there any way I can change this behavior, such as a toggle in Settings?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the behavior by going into Settings under Remotes and Devices.

In the Remote section, there will be an option called Home Button. Tap the option to switch the location the home button sends you to. Since Apple TV automatically sets it to TV app after updating, you just need to press once to restore normal behavior, and again to switch to launching the TV app when the home button is pressed.